# SQLiteDatabase Change Two Text Views in a ListView From 2 Table Columns

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm using an SQLiteDatabase to record 2 types of data under a single table (*COL_TASK_TITLE*, and *COL_TASK_WEIGHT*). I'm then using an ArrayAdapter to set the 2 TaskEntry's strings to their 2 relevant TextViews (*characterNameDisplay*, and *characterWeightDisplay*). These TextView are both part of the same ListView element (*item_todo*).

This is the method I'm calling to update the ListView:

```
public void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_WEIGHT},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
        int idx1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_WEIGHT);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx1));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.characterNameDisplay,
                taskList);

        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Currently, it is setting both TaskEntry's to just the *characterNameDisplay* TextView in seperate ListView segments.

My question is; how do I correctly set each TextView to their relevant TaskEntry's?

e.g. *characterWeightDisplay* to *COL_TASK_WEIGHT*; and *characterNameDisplay* to *COL_TASK_TITLE*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `List<String>` and adding both the task name and task weight as individual elements of this list. There is no way for `ArrayAdapter` (or anything else) to know that two adjacent items are related--everything looks like individual elements of the list.

You should create a class to encapsulate the attributes of a task:

```
class Task {
    String name;
    String weight;
    // add more as needed
}
```

Then when you process the Cursor, you make a list of `Task`s instead:

```
List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_TASK_TITLE));
    String weight= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_TASK_WEIGHT));
    Task task = new Task();
    task.name = name;
    task.weight = weight;
    taskList.add(task);
}
```

This also means your adapter will be an `ArrayAdapter<Task>` instead. However, now this adapter probably does not have necessary logic to bind a `Task` to the layout you've defined for the list rows. At the very least, you would have to override `getView()` and implement that yourself.

In my opinion, it's worth not using `ArrayAdapter` because it's generally too simple for most applications; instead you should subclass `BaseAdapter`. Even better would be to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`, since `ListView` is old and clunky.

Comment: As you think it would be best, I will research RecyclerView and replace my ListView with it. Would a RecyclerView require me to change my SQLiteDatabase?

Comment: @TomJames Everything discussed here is in regards to UI, none of it should require any changes to the way you store persistent data.